# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@74e9fb2d

Tags: java, android, gradle, symbols, resolve

Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@74e9fb2d.
[Image screenshot of my android loginpage project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qC4z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qC4z.png)

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Please copy and paste your codes here instead of using image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about not provided the right resource type in your code. The attached screenshot don't provide any further information that we can utilize to help you.